# How to add a dynamically concatenated file name for "include" tag in Selmer (Clojure)?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, template-engine, selmer

I'm new to **Clojure**. My issue is regarding **[selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer)** templating library.

What I want to do is apply a variable for following way. But its not working;

```
{% include  {{right-page}} %} -------  X
```

*(here **right-page** is a concatenated sting for a target file name)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If right-page is a valid string you're passing to the page, I think this will work for you

`{% include right-page %}`

Comment: This doesn't work. Selmer works on pre-caching the full page. A runtime value for the template name will *not* work. The other answer by @Marty Gentillon is correct

Answer (score 3):

Any targets for including in selmer must currently be known when selmer compiles the template, which it does without the passed in data.  This means that, given the template:

template.html_template:

```
{% include right-page %}
```

and the clojure code:

```
(selmer/render-file template.html_template 
                    {right-page "some/other/template/file.html_template})
```

You can expect an exception.  As for a work around, you might consider

```
(selmer/render-file template.html_template 
  {right-page (selmer/render-file 
                "some/other/template/file.html_template {})})
```

or something similar.

You will, of course have to update template.html to include the already rendered text, and to disable escaping,  like so:

template.html_template:

```
{{right-page|safe}}
```